# Python - Grids, random integers in cells

Tags: python, grid

I've been trying to create an `n` x `n` grid of elevation values (in meters), a peak is a grid point for which all four neighboring cells (North, South, East, West) are strictly lower. When the function is run, random integers from `0`-`9` are shown in the cells.

Sample Run (`n == 5`):

```
2 6 1 7 5
6 8 3 2 6
5 4 1 6 4
4 6 9 5 3
3 4 8 1 2
```

In the grid above, there are 3 peaks: `8`, `6`, and `9`. Likewise, indicate the coordinates (row and column indices) of the peaks in the printed peak values.

For example, `"peak: 8m @ location 1,1"`, `"peak: 6m @ location 2,3"`, and so on.

Likewise, indicate the coordinates (row and column indices) of the peaks in the printed peak values. Indices should start at zero, that is, the upper left corner is at index `0,0`.

Partial code:

```
import numpy as np
import random
n = 5
grid = np.array([random.randrange(10) for i in range(n**2)])
print grid.reshape(n,n)

for row in range(1,n+1):
for col in range(1,n+1):
    if grid[row][col] > grid[row-1][col] :
        cell = random.randrange(10)
        grid.append(cell)

    if grid[row][col] > grid[row+1][col]:
        cell = random.randrange(10)
        grid.append(cell)

    if grid[row][col] > grid[row][col+1]:
        cell = random.randrange(10)
        grid.append(cell)

    if grid[row][col] > grid[row][col-1]:
        cell = random.randrange(10)
        grid.append(cell)


print grid
```

I don't know how to implement the conditions of the "peak". And the second part is really wonky.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Uhm I have a hard time creating the 2d list where integers are randomized.

Comment: @TonyGarangean do you mean `[[random.randrange(10) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]`?

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to not use that function? Or other way? cause that list comprehension isn't allowed for us.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, I did that one.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I have difficulty implementing the conditions of the peak values in the randomized matrix.

Comment: @TonyGarangean this isn't a code-writing service; **do your own homework**.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your question has two parts.  Generating the map, and finding the peaks.

Part 1: generate a random map

```
from random import randint
map = []

for y in range(rows):
    row = []
    for x in range(columns):
        row.append(randint(0, 9))
    map.append(row)
```

This should out put a result that looks something like:

```
map = [
    [5, 3, 4, 4, 6],
    [1, 2, 8, 2, 5],
    [8, 2, 4, 2, 5],
    [9, 5, 9, 6, 3],
    [3, 8, 9, 7, 4]
    ]
```

Part 2: find the peaks

```
peaks = [] # list to store peaks

for row in range(map):
    for col in range(row): # col is short for column

        peak = True
        height = map[row][col]
        # if adjacent square is higher
        # each coordinate has to be checked to see if it is in range
        if 0 <= row -1 and map[row-1][col] >= height:
            peak = False
        elif row + 1 < len(map) and map[row+1][col] >= height:
            peak = False
        elif 0 <= col - 1 and map[row][col-1] >= height:
            peak = False
        elif col + 1 < len(map[row]) and map[row][col+1] >= height:
            peak = False

        if peak: # if taller than adjacent squares
            peaks.append((row, col)) # add coordinates to peak list
```

Using the map generated in the first code, we can expect to see the following result.

```
peaks = [
    (0, 0),
    (4, 0),
    (1, 2),
    (3, 0),
    ]
```